# how can i load controller based on useragent?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, routes

I have 2 different sites for mobile and desktop(i cannot make it responsive  due to very large difference in them, so cant load different views), and their urls are same. I already have mobile site in Codeigniter, i need to make it for desktop version.

> Is their any way so that i can load different controllers in router
>   based on useragent, or any other way to solve this.

I have tried loading useragent library before the routing rules and i am getting error.

This is what i tried in routes.php:

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
$this->load->helper('url');
if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
{
    $device = "";
}
else
{
    $device = "desktop/";
}
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Undefined property: CI_Router::$load
>       Filename: config/routes.php
>       Line Number: 52
>       Backtrace:
>       File: /var/www/html/abc.com/application/config/routes.php
>       Line: 52
>       Function: _error_handler
>       File: /var/www/html/buzz.in/index.php
>       Line: 315
>       Function: require_once

Comment: Instead of routes, please try it using BaseController and then route the requests.

Comment: I'd say use codeigniter hooks for this, that way you can execute checks before the controller is loaded

Comment: thanks everyone for help. Hooks worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you could use as above is using a remap function, or use the baseController, but I would go for CodeIgniter hooks.

Next to that I wonder why mobile would handle data differently from desktop? In my experience I only change the view, not functionality but anyhow check this

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_remap()` function after checking user-agent and it will keep the URL same in both case (mobile/desktop).

[_remap() documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)

Or you can check it in BaseController as stated by @kishor10d...